# Replace the n-th occurrences of string in files recursively

Tags: shell, unix, sed, count, grep

I need to replace the string of n-th occurrences that exists inside files.

The case is like this:

I have 1,000 occurrences of `Acme` inside files, which I managed to obtain the number through:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | grep -c 'Acme'
```

I also had been able to replace *all* occurrences of `Acme` through:

```
grep -rl 'Acme' ./ | LC_ALL=C xargs sed -i '' 's/Acme/NotAcme/g'
```

However, I face difficulty when I try to only replace the n-th occurrences (E.g. Only replace the first 100 occurrences of `Acme`.

The furthest I found is to iterate through all the occurrences of `Acme` through:

```
grep -roh Acme . | wc -w
```

Haven't found the way to iterate and replace the n-th occurrences of `Acme` so far.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `string{,100}` should do it.

Comment: Hi @chovy can you please elaborate more about it? Thanks!

Comment: regex has a modifier? dont' know what tis called where you can do `thing{min,max}` if you leave `min` empty it will be 0 by default. so `string{,100}` should match the first 100

Comment: edit: actually this doesn't work based on your requirements.

Comment: `$ cat test | grep -E "Acme{1,4}"` this would match all files that have "Acme" at least 1 to 4 times.....if there are 8 Acme's it would still match.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155805/sed-replace-first-k-instances-of-a-word-in-the-file

Comment: this is `supposed` to work but doesn't for me: `$ sed 's/Acme/NotAcme/g4' test`

Comment: added an ansewer

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/Acme/ && ++n <= 4 { sub(/Acme/, "Notacme") } { print }' test 
1 Notacme
2 Notacme
3 Notacme
FOO
4 Notacme
5 Acme
6 Acme
BAR
7 Acme
8 Acme
```

THis works. Just replace 4 with "N"

Comment: Thanks @chovy this works! I wonder if this can be modified so that we can have a range of occurrences to replace?

Like setting value for n

E.g. n=30; and then checking if n<=40 (Only replacing from 30th into 40th occurrences)?

Thanks a lot again for your answer!

Comment: Keep in mind it only operates one per line. so may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Only replace the first 100 occurrences of `Acme`:

You may use this `find | gnu-awk` solution:

```bash
find . -type f -exec awk -v RS='Acme' -v repl='NotAcme' -v n=100 '{
   ORS = (NR <= n ? repl : RT)} 1' {} \;
```

This awk command sets `Acme` as record separator, enabling `awk` to split records on each occurrence of string `Acme`. We keep a max count of replacements `100` in variable `n`. When current record count `NR` is less than equal to `n` then we output `repl` otherwise we output `RT` which is same as value matched by `RS`

Comment: @Raymond: Did this work out?